# var in C# - Why can't it be used as a member variable?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, clr, implicit-typing

Why is it not possible to have implicitly-typed variables at a class level within C# for when these variables are immediately assigned?

ie:

```
public class TheClass
{
    private var aList = new List<string>();
}
```

Is it just something that hasn't been implemented or is there a conceptual/technical reason for why it hasn't been done?

Comment: That's called a _field_, not a member variable.

Comment: I thought they meant the same thing, one is from Java and the other from C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here's a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) from Eric that explains the reasoning.

Comment: Ah that's a great blog - thanks